# Return polymorphic object in real-time critical code

Tags: c++, polymorphism, real-time

**Is it possible in C++ to have a function return a polymorphic object in a way that is real-time safe?**

For context:  I want to implement a function that returns information about errors detected in a system.  My first naive approach was to implement it like this (simplified):

```
class Error { ... };  // abstract base class
// different error cases:
class FooError: public Error { public: FooError(int foo) {...}};
class BarError: public Error { public: BarError(int bar, float baz) {...}};

// check if there is an error and return the first one detected
std::shared_ptr<Error> get_error() {
    if (is_error_foo()) {
        return std::make_shared<FooError>(42);
    }
    if (is_error_bar()) {
        return std::make_shared<BarError>(13, 3.14);
    }

    ...
}
```

Now the problem is that the code is for a real-time critical system and hence should not use dynamic memory allocation.  Therefore I should not use `make_shared`.
Is there an alternative way to implement the above that does not use dynamic memory allocation (or other things that should not be done in real-time code)?

Comment: Polymorphism != dynamic allocation. Those concepts are completely orthogonal.

Comment: @Quimby I never implied they are the same.  The problematic part is the use of `make_shared` which to my understanding does do dynamic allocation.

Comment: You must have dynamic allocation for the data to be shared. You *could* create one of each object in advance, and just share them. A second shared_ptr for the same object doesn't need any new allocations, it just updates the existing one.

Comment: @BoP This might be a good solution, maybe consider posting it as an answer?

Comment: @luator You ask about polymorphism yet your issue is allocation, that is unrelated. You could return raw pointers to some static objects and you would still get polymorphism, there is no requirement to use dynamic allocation (in the form of shared pointers or any other) to get polymorphism. If you need the *shareability* 
 or different lifetimes, then of course, but again that is another question.

Comment: @Quimby I never implied that I have to use dynamic allocation to get polymorphism.
Indeed, I "could return raw pointers to some static objects".  That would be a valid answer to the question.

Comment: Assuming `is_error_foo()` and `is_error_bar()` both have predictable timing behaviour (and accounting for the fact both will be called if `is_error_foo()` returns `false`) one alternative is to throw an exception, and catch a `const Error &`.    The timing to throw and catch an exception will generally be predictable if the immediate caller does the catching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A base class making message collection high performance can be done as:

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

using MessageParam = std::variant<int, float>;

template<typename T>
concept MessageType = std::is_constructible_v<MessageParam, T>;

template<int MAX_PARAM>
class Message
{
public:
    template<MessageType ... Args>
    Message(std::string_view format, Args... args)
        requires (sizeof...(args) <= MAX_PARAM) :
        m_format(format),
        m_nr_params(sizeof...(args)),
        m_params{ args... }
    {}

    auto msg() const
    {
        // Some formatting, this is just an example:
        assert(m_format.data() + m_format.size() == '\0' && "Messages require null terminated strings to use boost format");
        boost::format fmt{ m_format.data() }; 
        for (size_t i = 0; i < m_nr_params; ++i)
        {
            if (std::holds_alternative<float>(m_params[i]))
            {
                fmt% std::get<float>(m_params[i]);
            }
            if (std::holds_alternative<int>(m_params[i]))
            {
                fmt% std::get<int>(m_params[i]);
            }
        }
        return fmt.str();
    }

private:
    std::string_view m_format;
    size_t m_nr_params;
    std::array<MessageParam, MAX_PARAM> m_params;
};

using MyMessageBase = Message<3>;

class NumberTooBigMessage : public MyMessageBase
{
public:
    explicit NumberTooBigMessage(int number) : 
        MyMessageBase("Number is too big: %1%", number) 
    {}
};

auto alternative_number_to_big_message(int number)
{
    return MyMessageBase("Number is too big: %1%", number);
}

void test()
{
    std::vector<MyMessageBase> messages;
    messages.push_back(NumberTooBigMessage(1));
    messages.push_back(alternative_number_to_big_message(1));

    for (auto& message : messages)
    {
        std::cout << message.msg();
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this approach.  I think I can't use C++20 due to compatibility reasons but I guess it should be possible to do something similar without it.

Comment: I chose this one as accepted answer as it fit best for my needs but other answers have good suggestions as well.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use runtime polymorphism when you don't want runtime polymorphism. (public) inheritance is not the solution to everything, don't make it your first choice. I see basically two ways to avoid dynamic allocations:

- `std::variant<FooError,BarError>` does not dynically allocate memory
- keep only the `Error` with a `std::string message` and let `get_error` build that string based on the error conditions. Typically, in the end all you need is an error message. If you need more information consider to encode it in enum members, eg `enum ErrorType {Foo,Base};`

Comment: Building the `std::string` in `get_error` would again require dynamic allocation, so I would need to work with a fixed-size string in this case (which is possible but a bit annoying).  Using `variant` might be an option, though, I'll look into it.

Comment: @luator You can have a set of compiled strings and refer to them with std::string_view, to avoid dynamic allocation. (If your error messages do not contain any variable information)

Comment: @Aedoro Unfortunately they *do* have variable information.  That's why I started using separate classes (they are basically containers for those variables with a `get_message()` method to construct the message later outside of the real-time-critical loop).

Comment: @luator ok if you do have variable information you need to store the variables alongside a formatting string. The issue is that to avoid dynamic allocation this may not by a vector. If all your messages have a small amount of variables you can use something like std::array<int, N> along side a formatting string (as string_view) to represent the message.

Comment: @luator I think you have to make up your mind on what you need/want. The real issue is neither the smart pointer nor the dynamic memory allocation but that you focus on dynamic information (which then needs dynamic allocation and is best managed by a smart pointer). How would you reorganize the information when you did not have `FooError` or `BarError` but only one `Error` ? What needs to be in? What are the different cases to be covered?

Answer (score 1):

You can for example pre-allocate memory and use "placement new" operator. This is a common technique in real-time systems to avoid dynamic memory allocation during critical operations.

Here is an example of using placement 'new' with shared_ptr.
When the std::shared_ptr goes out of scope, the custom deleter will be called.

```
#include <memory>

class alignas(sizeof(size_t)) TestClass 
{

public:

TestClass() {}

~TestClass() {}

};

int main()
{
    char buffer_to_be_used[sizeof(TestClass)];

    //Using of placement new
    TestClass* myObj = new (buffer_to_be_used) TestClass();

    // shared pointer with custom deleter -> it looks a bit tricky...
    std::shared_ptr<TestClass> ptr(myObj, [](TestClass* obj) { obj->~TestClass(); });

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I didn't know about the placement new operator, it sounds very useful.  I think your answer would benefit from an example code snipped that shows how to use it.

Comment: Here is an example of using placement 'new' with shared_ptr.


    #include <memory>

    class alignas(sizeof(size_t)) TestClass 
    {

    public:

    TestClass() {}

    ~TestClass() {}

    };

    int main()
    {
        char buffer_to_be_used[sizeof(TestClass)];

        //Using of placement new
        TestClass* myObj = new (buffer_to_be_used) TestClass();

        // shared pointer with custom deleter -> it looks a bit tricky...
        std::shared_ptr<TestClass> ptr(myObj, [](TestClass* obj) { obj->~TestClass(); });

        return 0;
    }